# sails.io.js with Svelte3/4 SvelteKit

Tags: sails.js, svelte, sveltekit, sails.io.js, socket.io-client

I've been trying to port my app from older *Svelte3/Rollup* to newer *Vite* based setup and am having trouble initializing *sails.io.js client* to work inside Svelte. 
What used to work really well in the past with *Svelte3/Rollup* was:
Inside **/public/index.html** (after manually placing `sails.io.js` into `/public/libs`:

```
<script src="/libs/sails.io.js" autoConnect="false"></script>
```

Inside **/src/global-state.js** (my global persistent vars):

```
export var mySocket;
import io from 'io';    // this 'io' global would resolve fine!
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
mySocket = io.sails.connect();
```

Then it was just a matter of importing `mySocket` variable into any svelte component.
But with newer *Svelte/Vite* versions this approach doesn't work anymore.
Obviously I now place `sails.io.js` inside `/static/libs` and it is located fine by `<script>` tag in the HTML.

Then calling `import io from 'io'` gives me a `Cannot find module 'io' imported from '....../src/global-state.js'` error, which is the heart of my question!

What I've tried, and none of which worked was:

- Installing `npm install sails.io.js`, then doing `import io from 'sails.io.js';` which imports but gives me an `undefined` object with which I can do nothing useful...
- As a continuation of the above, trying to deal with the `io` object inside `onMount()` function, which still resolves to `undefined`.
- Trying to force a global alias inside `vite.config.js` as per [this workaround](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4798#issuecomment-925689898). Gives a bunch of errors.

I would really appreciate any clues as to how to proceed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No promises beacuse I've never used sails before, but try this out:

First install both `sails.io.js` and `socket.io-client` via NPM.

```bash
npm install socket.io-client --save
npm install sails.io.js --save
```

Then, in `global-state.js`, use the below code to set up the client:

```js
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import sailsIOClient from 'sails.io.js';

const io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';

export const mySocket = io.sails.connect();
```

You shouldn't need `<script src="/libs/sails.io.js" />` or anything in the `/public/libs` directory

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked 90%, it got me to the point where the client initialized but now wouldn't connect to Sails.js server. After digging deeper I've discovered that `sails.io.js` only works with `socket.io-client` version 2.0.3, as per [here](https://github.com/0xGREG/sails-ub-poc/pull/1). So if you could edit the first line of your answer code to be `npm install socket.io-client@2.0.3 --save --save-exact` this would complete the answer. Thanks again!